# Automatically check checbox when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a check box and a submit button. I would like the checkbox to be checked automatically when I submit the form.

How can I do that with jquery or javascript?

Comment: what do you intend to do & what you have done?

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of having a checkbox.

Comment: Why have the check box at all if it will always be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
})
```

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sedcv

Comment: You should use `prop` in place of `attr` . Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: Good call. The jQuery team seemed to have cleaned that up nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have HTML like this

```
<form>
    Are you sure ?<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Script

```
$(function(){

    $("form").submit(function(){
        $("#chk1").prop("checked", true);
        alert("going to submit now");
    });        

});
```

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/TCaUk/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
   $('#checkboxId').prop('checked', true);
   return true;
});
```

Comment: Wont it work without `return true` ? Dont take it otherwise , I have never seen `return true`

Comment: I get it :) I was just curious that I would have missed something important. (I've learned in parts, so I usually dont know a lot of small things)

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure what the purpose is, you can use jQuery selectors.

http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
​<input name="foo" type="checkbox">
<input type="button" id="button" value="check checkbox">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JQUERY:**

```
​$("#button").bind('click', function(){
    $('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);
});​​​​​​
```

**JSFIDDLE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ycqZa/

Comment: This is not fired if the user submits the form using the enter key.

Comment: He/she said submit button, I just focused on that and ignored the fact that he/she may want to submit the form with the enter key (oops :P), I however still showed how to check a checkbox using jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead, if you want the check box already checked, you can have it disabled, to prevent the user from unchecking it and to have it automatically checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="uniquename" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
```